# Completing the square of a second order polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am working on a problem that requires me to find the form of the linear polynomial f(x) that will make the expression under the square root sign at most a square of a polynomial of 2nd degree :

$\sqrt {x - 2{x^2} - {A_1}{x^4} - {A_2}{x^3} - {A_3}{x^2} - {A_4}x - {A_5} + f(x)\left( {{x^2} - {x^3}} \right)} $

The "A"s are constants while f(x) is a linear polynomial.  I  was able to solve this by first writing $f(x) = P + Qx \  $   and then  equating  the terms under the square root sign to $ {\left( {B{x^2} + Cx + D} \right)^2}\ $.   The values of P,Q B, C and D were also found this way in terms of the constants .  But the method is a bit tedious. Is there a more elegant way of getting this done?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for $f(x),B,C,D$ such that
$$x-2x^2-A_1x^4-A_2x^3-A_3x^2-A_4x-A_5=(x^3-x^2)f(x)+\left(Bx^2+ Cx+D\right)^2.$$
Rewriting the data (the LHS) in a more condensed way, this equation becomes:
$$x^2h(x)+\alpha x+\beta=x^2(x-1)f(x)+\left(Bx^2+ Cx+D\right)^2,$$
which is equivalent to
$$D^2=\beta,\quad2CD=\alpha,\quad h(x)=(x-1)f(x)+B^2x^2+2BCx+2BD+C^2$$
$C,D$ are given by the two first equations. Then $B$ is given by the quadratic equation
$$B^2+2B(C+D)+C^2=h(1).$$

Comment: Thank you very much.